# Disable Eureka client initialization during JUnit test run

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have this Junit 5 test which is used to test Rest API calls:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private ListsService listsService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void restTest() throws Exception {

        .....
    }
}
```

Into the project dependencies I have Eureka server dependency. Every time when I run this Junit test Eureka client is also started. How I can disable it? I don't need to run it. Looks like `@SpringBootTest` is also including Eureka client when test is run?

Error:

```
2023-06-28T18:28:59.213+03:00  WARN 9104 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/MICROSERVICE": Connect to http://localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
2023-06-28T18:28:59.213+03:00  WARN 9104 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MICROSERVICE/localhost:MICROSERVICE:8798 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the property below to test's `application.properties`:

```
eureka.client.enabled=false
```

or add the property directly to `@SpringBootTest` annotation:

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = "eureka.client.enabled=false")
```

---

If you use that class to test the web layer, consider replacing `@SpringBootTest` with [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html), to prevent loading the whole application context, which will make your test run faster.

> Using the `@WebMvcTest` annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@JsonComponent`, `Converter`/`GenericConverter`, `Filter`, `WebMvcConfigurer` and `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` beans but not `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` beans).

For more details refer to [Testing MVC Web Controllers with Spring Boot and @WebMvcTest](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-web-controller-test/).